# R expss use_labels and dplyr logic

Tags: r, dplyr, expss

I trying to get expss use_labels to work with dplyr logic - see example below.

The vignette states the following under use_labels. 
By now variable labels support available only for expressions which will be evaluated inside data.frame.
Is this the issue I'm having here?

#

```
##########################################
library(expss)
library(tidyverse)
data(mtcars)
mtcars = apply_labels(mtcars,
                      mpg = "Miles/(US) gallon",
                      cyl = "Number of cylinders",
                      disp = "Displacement (cu.in.)",
                      hp = "Gross horsepower",
                      drat = "Rear axle ratio",
                      wt = "Weight (1000 lbs)",
                      qsec = "1/4 mile time",
                      vs = "Engine",
                      vs = c("V-engine" = 0,
                             "Straight engine" = 1),
                      am = "Transmission",
                      am = c("Automatic" = 0,
                             "Manual"=1),
                      gear = "Number of forward gears",
                      carb = "Number of carburetors"
)

# table with caption from label - labels working
cro_cpct(mtcars$am, mtcars$vs) %>% set_caption(var_lab(mtcars$am))

## This works as expected - now to get this with expss use_labels.
mtcars %>%
 group_by(am) %>%
  summarise(
   freq = n()
)
#######
#am             freq
#<labelled>    <int>
# 1 0             19
# 2 1             13
########################

#### This doesn't work - i.e. not labelled
use_labels(mtcars %>%
  group_by(am) %>%
   summarise(
    freq = n()
))
## Error in substitute_symbols(expr, c(substitution_list, list(..data = quote(expss::vars(other))))) : 
  # argument "expr" is missing, with no default
```

If labels can't be used with dplyr logic does anyone know another package that can do labels with dplyr?
Regards

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `...data` parameter to access data in expression and `values2labels` (Thanks to @Gregory Demin) to get the labels.

```
library(expss)  
use_labels(mtcars, ..data %>% 
                      group_by(am) %>% 
                      summarise(freq = n()) %>% values2labels)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  Transmission  freq
#  <labelled>   <int>
#1 Automatic       19
#2 Manual          13
```

Comment: Thanks for this but there are NO labels in the tibble. The labels are like Automatic & Manual

Comment: ahh..I see. Sorry I couldn't find a way to do that. I'll try to check later.

Comment: @MarkWebb `use_labels` is for variable_labels. In `summarise` value labels are preserved but is not shown in the result. To show them use `values2labels` as last action in your chain, just after the summarize.

Comment: @GregoryDemin Thanks, that is new to me. Would you mind if I update that part in my answer? Or do you want to post it as separate answer ?

Comment: @RonakShah It's better that you update your answer. There is no reasons for two almost identical posts.

Comment: Thanks you guys - much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Package foreign does keep the value labels. Haven does not, or at least not by default and I can't figure out how to make it happen. You can confirm this by inspecting `str()` of the imported data. If you don't see the labels in there somewhere, they didn't get imported. Here I'm importing a Stata data set with value labels for union and female, both of which are 0/1 underlying. The `cro_cpct` command uses the value labels, but not the variable labels, when imported with package foreign (`read.dta`). When imported with package haven (`read_dta`), `cro_cpct` uses the variable labels but not the value labels.

```
    library(expss)
    library(tidyverse)
    library(foreign)
    wages <- read.dta("c:/users/pjargowsky/documents/course/qm2/wages.dta")
    cro_cpct(wages$female, wages$union) %>% set_caption(var_lab(wages$female))

#
# |              |              | wages$union |      |
# |              |              |          no |  yes |
# | ------------ | ------------ | ----------- | ---- |
# | wages$female |         male |        50.5 | 70.8 |
# |              |       female |        49.5 | 29.2 |
# |              | #Total cases |       438.0 | 96.0 |

library(haven)
wages <- read_dta("c:/users/pjargowsky/documents/course/qm2/wages.dta")
cro_cpct(wages$female, wages$union) %>% set_caption(var_lab(wages$female))

# Gender                                                    
# |        |              | Union Membership |      |
# |        |              |                0 |    1 |
# | ------ | ------------ | ---------------- | ---- |
# | Gender |            0 |             50.5 | 70.8 |
# |        |            1 |             49.5 | 29.2 |
# |        | #Total cases |            438.0 | 96.0 |
```

Comment: Could you try `wages = add_labelled_class(wages)` after the import with haven? Will it works?

Comment: Greg, that did not work for me. Is there an option on read_dta() that I need?

Comment: Could you start with clean session and load expss after the haven package? After that try  again `wages = add_labelled_class(wages)`.   If it won't work, please provide result of the `dput(wages[1:10, c("female","union")])`.

Comment: Greg, I think I figured it out. The Stata data set that was my target is very old (2002). Who knows what version of Stata that was. I've used in teaching for years. I re-saved it as Stata 16 dataset. Now package foreign won't even read it, but package haven does and the value labels are included and used. Thanks for your help.